# get all record of last month with respect to current month in sql server

Tags: sql-server, database

i have to two tables payment_tbl and bill_tbl with following attributes

```
payment_tbl (payment_ID int -> pk)
bill_tbl (payment_ID int -> Fk
         ,bill_IssueDate date
         ,bill_status varchar
         ,bill_amount type int
         )
```

---

so if i want to know which payment_ID has bill status 'Not Paid' in last month with respect to current month, let now month is Feb 2017 i want to know in jan 2017 who Did not paid Bill.

---

i tried following query but it return me empty column names

```
SELECT p.payment_ID
      ,b.amount_To_Pay
FROM bill_tbl AS b
    INNER JOIN payment_tbl AS p
        ON b.payment_id = p.payment_ID
WHERE b.bill_status = 'Not Paid'
    AND b.bill_IssueDate >= DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)
    AND b.bill_IssueDate < DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0,  GETDATE()) + 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the first of the current and previous months and set your range to that.

```
select 
    p.payment_ID, 
    b.amount_To_Pay 
FROM 
    bill_tbl AS b 
    INNER JOIN payment_tbl AS p ON 
    b.payment_id = p.payment_ID 
WHERE
    (b.bill_status = 'Not Paid')
    and b.bill_IssueDate < DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0)
    and b.bill_IssueDate >= DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, dateadd(month,-1,getdate())), 0)
```

Comment: it return me nothing even my bill table has date 2/2/2017 12:00:00 AM which is one month old

Comment: well it's currently February so last month is January....@mjunaid you said you wanted last month.  2/2/2017 is not one month old, that's one DAY old

Comment: @mjunaid what does that mean?

Comment: i was doing stupid mistake, in my bill table i entered wrong date now i corrected it and now my all queries working fine ,

Answer (score 0):

SHOULD BE AS SIMPLE AS -

```
SELECT p.payment_ID
  ,b.amount_To_Pay
FROM bill_tbl AS b
INNER JOIN payment_tbl AS p
    ON b.payment_id = p.payment_ID
WHERE b.bill_status = 'Not Paid'
AND DATEDIFF(month, b.bill_IssueDate ,getdate()) = 1
```

you have something else wrong, your date range is ok, get rid of some of the WHERE clauses and see if there actually is any data for those months - I don't think it is your date range

Comment: why its returning me empty table ?

Comment: this would return only partial month data... not the entire month of the previous month which is what OP wants

Comment: @mjunaid - I don't know, something else is wrong I think, are the records you want actually here, is the status correct?

Comment: @Cato sorry i was doing a stupid , worst stupid mistake since morning 10am, now i got solution ops

Comment: were you wanting the previous month back to the month anniversary?  That might seem simple on dates like 03-feb-2017 where you do > 03-jan-2017' but it is less simple on dates like '31-march-2017' because there is no 31 in feb